# AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted never reached

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

I never reach

```
AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted
```

when I call

```
[AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
```

I always get one of the others and then only way I determine that it's restricted is by trying to setup the session and getting a nil returned for

```
[AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]
```

Something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

I got that state (AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted) when camera was forbidden in Settings -> Main -> Restrictions section (names could be slightly different due to localization). Also this forbids built-in camera application

Answer (score 0):

when you get .restricted result for `AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video)` you will change your iOS Setting Option.

- iOS 12 or Higher
  go to [Settings —> Screen Time —> App Limits -> Camera On]
- iOS 11 or lower
  go to [Settings -> Main -> Restrictions section -> Camera On]

and you get `.authorized` result.